# The data of the first row of the table should be displayed in bold only modifying the style.css (NOT table.html) file

Tags: css, web, fonts

The table.html shows a table with a list of football teams and their positions. The task was to ensure that the team name is centered next to the club logo, which I already did. Now I'm struggling with making the Data of the first placed club from the table.html data bold. I'm a beginner in CSS and would appreciate any help.

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

td img {
  max-width: 50px;
}

table tr:first-child {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

table tr:first-child td {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bundesliga Tabelle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <style>
    img {
      width: 20%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    table {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: grey;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <caption>Bundesliga Tabelle 21/22</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Platzierung</th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Tordifferenz</th>
      <th>Punkte</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Bayern</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Dortmund</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Freiburg</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Wolfsburg</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> RB Leipzip</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Leverkusen</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Mainz</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Union Berlin</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Mönchengladbach</td>
      <td>-1</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Hoffenheim</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Köln</td>
      <td>-3</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Bochum</td>
      <td>-8</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Hertha</td>
      <td>-12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Eintracht Frankfurt</td>
      <td>-4</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Stuttgart</td>
      <td>-4</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Augsburg</td>
      <td>-11</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Bielefeld</td>
      <td>-9</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Greuther Fürth</td>
      <td>-21</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the contents of table.html so we have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I added the table.html

Comment: Thank you. I've put your code inside a snippet, and replaced relative image paths with placeholder images so we have something to look at.

Answer (score 0):

`table tr:first-child` will select the first `<tr>` in every `<table>`. In your `<table>` the first row contains the header.

To get the first row with data, simply select the second row with `table tr:nth-child(2)`

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

td img {
  max-width: 50px;
}

table tr:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bundesliga Tabelle</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <style>
    img {
      width: 20%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    table {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: grey;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <caption>Bundesliga Tabelle 21/22</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Platzierung</th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Tordifferenz</th>
      <th>Punkte</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Bayern</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Dortmund</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Freiburg</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Wolfsburg</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> RB Leipzip</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Leverkusen</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Mainz</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Union Berlin</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Mönchengladbach</td>
      <td>-1</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Hoffenheim</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Köln</td>
      <td>-3</td>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Bochum</td>
      <td>-8</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Hertha</td>
      <td>-12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Eintracht Frankfurt</td>
      <td>-4</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Stuttgart</td>
      <td>-4</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Augsburg</td>
      <td>-11</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Bielefeld</td>
      <td>-9</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td><img src="https://placehold.co/100x100.png"> Greuther Fürth</td>
      <td>-21</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

This *could* have been avoided if the table header row was put in a `<thead>` tag and/or the data rows put in a `<tbody>` tag. But that is not relevant here since you stated to not change the HTML at all.